# How to fix error in microsofot visual studio while installing package phat?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package

I run the following command in the command prompt

`py -3.7 -m pip install phat`

And i am getting the following error:

`error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'C:\Users\rabih\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rabih\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r5wlnxa3\\phat\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rabih\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ahhgu5et\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\rabih\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r5wlnxa3\phat\`

Is this related to the setup.py? How to fix this error in this case?
knowing that i am using anaconda and python 3.7 and i have installed microsoft visual c++ build tools and still didn't fix the error